# Replace data in mysql table if there is duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My page works as follows:

- A coach logs onto an admin page of a sports team
- He can then select his team for a forthcoming fixture
- The team is displayed in a dropdown menu. With a different dropdown
  menu for each different position. Thus ensuring only players relevant
  to a specific position is displayed in the dropdown menu
- Now the coach selects his team
- He then selects the opponents against whom the selected team will
  play
- He then clicks submit

When he clicks submit the isset() function is triggered which will upload the selected team to the selected_team table in my db

Ok that is easy enough and it is working. Here is my problem, lets say the coach wants to change his selection for a certain fixture. He then goes to the selection page again and redo the whole process described above. But what now happens is that the same fixture_id for opponents is uploaded to the database (only with different playernames where he changed his selection)

**Example:** Where Selection has been changed for a fixture
[image]

Notice: How that the old data from 1st selection is still there and the new data from second selection just gets added to the table

What im looking for is, should the user re select a team for a certain fixture **I want the new teams data to replace the old teams data.** How do I go about doing this?

Please note this is a fictional database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make fixture_id a unique or primary key field and use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM selected_team WHERE fixture_id = '{$fixture_id}';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I then get the error  Undefined variable: fixture_id as fixture_id is only a column in a table and not a variable in my code

Comment: Well, replace $fixture_id with whatever variable contains that ID. This will delete any rows with that ID, right before you re-add them.

Comment: @DavidHoude, but the dublicate data will continue to appear in a table.

Comment: @DavidHoude will it not then delete all the data in the fixture_id column?

Comment: It will delete only the rows with the ID that you are about to use. I.e: directly before your insert, run the delete. This will delete all rows with lets say fixture_id "1" and add the new rows with fixture_id "1"

Comment: Maximus: I upvoted your answer because I feel it was correct. I just wanted to give another option here. I am not sure how deleting all the duplicater rows before adding the new ones would create duplicate data though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to resend the fixture_id to change/edit page (by GET/POST) on clicking the edit fixture button (I assume) and then as Maximus mentioned, use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as the syntax described here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

or you can alternatively delete the key from the table manually.